# Super Mario 64 RNG

Tags: code-golf, random, game

## Introduction

Super Mario 64 has a heavily overcomplicated RNG, ably explained [here](http://youtu.be/MiuLeTE2MeQ) by Pannenkoek.

I thought it might be interesting to implement it.

## Challenge

Implement the RNG function, except for the two special cases.  (Not part of the below description; everything below is what you should implement.)

Input and output are both 16-bit integers.

The standard C implementation is as follows.  `&` is bitwise-AND, `^` is bitwise-XOR.  Shifts have higher precedence than bitwise operations, so `(s0 & 0xFF)<<1 ^ input` does the left-shift before XORing with `input`.

```
rng(input) {
    s0 = (input & 0xFF) << 8;                       // shift low byte to high
    s0 = s0 ^ input;
    input = (s0 & 0xFF) << 8 | (s0 & 0xFF00) >> 8;  // swap 8-bit halves
    s0 = (s0 & 0xFF) << 1 ^ input;
    s1 = s0 >> 1 ^ 0xFF80;
    if(s0 & 1) input = s1 ^ 0x8180;              // XOR with one of 2 constants
    else       input = s1 ^ 0x1FF4;              // depending on s0 odd or even
    return input;
}
```

In math notation, where \$\oplus\$ is bitwise XOR and \$x_L\$ is \$x\$ mod 256:

\begin{equation}
\text{rng}(a):= \text{let } \begin{array}{l}     b = 256a_L \oplus a \\
    c = 256b_L \oplus \lfloor b/256 \rfloor \\
d = 32256 \text{ if $c$ odd, } 57460 \text{ otherwise}\end{array}
\text{ in }
b_L \oplus \lfloor c/2 \rfloor \oplus d.
\end{equation}

## Example input and output

The number just before an arrow should be taken to the number just after it, so \$f(1789)\$ should be \$0\$, and \$f(0)\$ should be \$57460\$.
\$22026\$ and \$58704\$ map to each other.

```
12567 -> 60400 -> 1789 -> 0 -> 57460 -> 55882 -> 50550
64917 -> 43605 -> 21674 -> 46497 -> 45151
22026 <-> 58704
```

## Rules

Shortest code wins.
[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: challenges should be self contained; a youtube link and sample implementation aren't a substitute for a solid spec. Make sure you're [sandboxing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) challenges to catch stuff like this ahead of time.

Comment: Um. The implementation is the spec. There's not really a simpler way to write this spec, _because_ it's an overcomplicated RNG.

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting the spec to be slightly less "C", to make it a little more agnostic. For example, removing the types would make it a lot simpler to understand, without significantly detracting from the code. As would outright removing the commented lines - if it doesn't need to be implemented, don't even include it in the spec

Comment: will `(uint8_t)input << 8` always be 0?

Comment: Can the input be negative? Or is it guaranteed to be non-negative?

Comment: I can't read that specification. Could you please re-state it in either English or mathematical formulas?

Comment: I also can't read that specification, but also not mathematical formulas.  Could you re-state it in English, please?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen: I added a quick English guide to the C notation; IDK if that helps at all.  (Lynn added math formulas.)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen: Also, the linked youtube video walks through the C code with English descriptions of the steps.  That's not ideal for a code-golf question, but perhaps helpful, and something someone could maybe transcribe if they wanted to.

Comment: @WheatWizard: I added an explanation of that section.  It's a PRNG, so it's showing the sequence of `seed` values.  (Since this is a bad old PRNG where the output is the whole internal state.)

Comment: What is unreadable about the C code? most languages use similar operators

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Input is guaranteed to be either (a) between 0 and 65535 inclusive, or (b) a native 16-bit integer, to be treated as unsigned.

Comment: Should $c$ in the math notation be the OR of its lo and hi bytes? or it does it cancel out with the final expression? I think having a new line for $c$ is easier to understand than let ... in notation. Are the "let" expressions 3 lines? I read it line by line and was confused

Answer (score 24):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 21 bytes

```
89 C8 30 C4 86 C4 D1 E8 73 04 66 35 74 9E 66 35 74 E0 30 C8 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFfT8MgHHwun@JnjQlsnWk3p8tqfTHZmy8@mThdGKUthlJT2kmz7Ktbwbn57@UXuDvuDmCjnLG@PxWKyTblcK2bVFTnxQ36BUmx/ovVQuX/dEI1DkOrFW2sYt02fLXCOKO6YVRKQsAqIMNuUhIjqkvA9z5G2dwrqw1wagLgzCDPVDXQIgAq7ZoV@XGji3ovi5D3ohjoL61FQjOLZuFzaKLF4gLp@Q9isfgm9rAMgFm7mjeI@LYKcp1KKtS@XJ0zKyhoDYOB3WwI2iLPMQYSiMbTy6sAuhh5aQWv9imaDPtnAvwATJJhQ0gMb4WQHLCBkwSm4XQa2hAPeQf1Ut1RVgjFgVUpn7sKnvMO96bbgw7OwvGD9e0SjFulRa54@llsQDLyaIbDJxLvDmGdCwvN7cS5HR2wbbbuGq7JUrmGjrT3bmvl0nao799ZJmmu@1E5GdthvyWxZ7n8AA)

Uses the `fastcall` calling convention – argument in ECX, result in EAX.

In assembly:

```
f:  mov eax, ecx
    xor ah, al
    xchg ah, al
    shr eax, 1
    jnc s
    xor ax, 0x8180^0x1FF4
s:  xor ax, 0xFF80^0x1FF4
    xor al, cl
    ret
```

Simplifications used:

- The XOR constants are combined.
- The `<< 1` cancels out with the later `>> 1`.
- The check `s0 & 1` is the same as the bit shifted out by the `>> 1`.

---

## x86 16-bit machine code, 18 bytes

```
89 C8 30 C4 C1 C8 09 73 04 35 74 1E 35 74 E0 30 C8 C3
```

In assembly:

```
f:  mov ax, cx
    xor ah, al
    ror ax, 9
    jnc s
    xor ax, 0x8180^0x1FF4^0x8000
s:  xor ax, 0xFF80^0x1FF4
    xor al, cl
    ret
```

Compared to the 32-bit program, this one saves two bytes by not needing operand-size prefixes.

One more byte is saved by combining the "swap bytes" and "shift right by 1" parts into a rotation right by 9 bits. This leaves [the bit that the original program would shift out] at the top of the register instead; fortunately, that is the same bit that is used to choose between the XOR constants, so it can be corrected for by adjusting those constants.

Comment: Nice.  I found it non-obvious how the shift-cancelling worked, but I think the idea is that the 8-bit `s0&0xFF` gets left and right shifted as part of something extended to 16-bit, so we're not knocking bits off either end of *it*.  After separating out the XORing, there's still a `input >> 1` that does need to happen as part of `s1 = s0 >> 1 ^ 0xFF80;`, and that's what the `shr` is doing.  (As well as setting CF= low bit of `s0`, since after that point in the source we only need `s1` which involves `input>>1`)

Comment: I wonder, would 8080 or 8086 machine code (16-bit) result in even shorter code?

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn Indeed it does. Added.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

```javascript
n=>(q=n>>8^(n&=255))/2^n<<7^n^57460^q%2*40564
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBjoIwGATgu08xl9XWAGKlRYPtbZ@CtEmDICr5q6JejM@O3extvpk5@5cfm/vp@kgpHNqp0xNpw26ajNk6RnMtpOR8JRzt96UjJ8tC5e72I5ZFLlUxVTVqrIVUZYISNolSxW4dJf8lRC5Ugg0s7Czrwv3XNz1jNSjBBZZDG7xnwNA@4KFR2yoq/liFS5pWoFh2jDiHz67PsY/x79EEGsPQZkM4Mp@dw4nYAqnBgsf5w6cv)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>34</s> <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₁‰`Ðr^‚₁β2‰`Ž$×*Žâ∊α^^
```

-12 bytes thanks to *@CommandMaster*

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPjo4YNCYcnFMU9apgF5J3bZAQSOLpX5fB0raN7Dy961NF1bmNc3P//hkamZuYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/R02Njxo2JByeUBT3qGEWkHdukxFI4OhelcPTtY7uPbzoUUfXuY1xcf91/kcbGpmameuYGZgYGOgYmltY6hjomJqbmAFJUwsLIx0zE0tDcx0TYzMDUx0jQzNzEx0ToJC5jpGRgZGZjqmFuYFJLAA).

**Explanation:**

05AB1E lacks bitshift builtins, so instead we'll use modulo/multiply where applicable.

```python
₁‰           # Divmod the (implicit) input-integer by 256
             # (since the input is guaranteed to be a 16-bit integer)
  `          # Pop and push both the quotient and remainder to the stack
   Ð         # Triplicate the remainder
    r        # Reverse the stack from q,r,r,r to r,r,r,q
     ^       # Bitwise-XOR the remainder and quotient together
‚            # Pair the r and r^q together
 ₁β          # Convert it from a base-256 list to a (base-10) integer
2‰           # Divmod it by 2
  `          # Pop and push quotient and remainder separated to the stack
   Ž$×       # Push compressed integer 25204
      *      # Multiply it to the remainder
       Žâ∊   # Push compressed integer 57460
          α  # Take the absolute difference of the two values
           ^ # Bitwise-XOR it to the quotient
^            # Bitwise-XOR it to third remainder-copy that was still on the stack
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž$×` is `25204` and `Žâ∊` is `57460`.

Comment: I don't believe *256 should be to the quotient - `quotient*256+remainder` is the original number. [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOjKhBrxQGJRw0bEg6tBPG0D607tD3OCCRwdK/K4elaR/ceXvSoo@vcxrj//03NTcwMAA) by not calculating `s1`

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPjhU0Jh1bGHVoHZGppGz1q2JBwdK/K4elaR/ceXvSoo@vcRqBc3P//puYmZgYA) by adding to that a more efficient method of calculating the first part

Comment: @CommandMaster Thanks for the golf. After seeing _m90_'s I had the feeling my port of the original C-code implementation could be simplified.

Comment: This solution is actually wrong - the `в` has to be `‰`, otherwise it fails on numbers between 1 to 255

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPjo4YNCYcnFMU9apgF5J3bZAQSOLpX5fB0raN7Dy961NF1bmNc3P//hkamZuYA)

Comment: @CommandMaster Nice! I did try to use a triplicate & reverse stack before like this ``₁‰`Ðr^s₁*+2‰`Ž$×*Žâ∊α^^``, but ended up at 23 bytes as well. Nice 1-byte save using the pair + base-256 conversion.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>53</s></sup> 52 bytes

```c
q;f(n){q=n>>8^(n&=255);n=q/2^n<<7^n^57460-q%2*'bt';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBhb4IwEP3ur7iQOEEhlkoBg/hl2a@YkLhaHNlWhTYZmeGvj53Qkblka9L2@u7de73j3pHzrquSwpbOpUrldhvntrxLKWNOItNqSXO52US5zFkUhMSrpnQ@e9KzpO1KqeFtX0rbgcsEcF0BLZRWjxmkcPEpCyMXQhIQ4oIfxWsXMOh18GJxTDEbrH0kBauQMBeoH0YBvhBFkFJCQ2TGEQnaZLQQzVlwLQ6Dy//yjDBG/pAPmM98I2/MjAs/SaWBP@/rOZ6Cv4h6MLN2zQPdNet73Mxy4ed7ZZnq4lSDff1oKQ@iwTKSmHADqvwQp8L@bsFZGmA@IgksFj3b6cWGyY7TRbVhwj0lS26yCrOFrZ1bVCA6jux32blGSmFb0wN4W8BzqnYSG9MuKHfsXaWpyIxsO2m7T1687o@q896/AA)

*Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250175/9481).

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 173 bytes

```
.+
16$*0$&$*
+`(1+)\1
$+0
01
1
.*(.{8})(.{8})
$2$1
(?<=1.{7})(1|(0))
$#2
1$
11001111001110100
^((.{8}).{7}).
$+0${1}1110000001110100
+`1(.{15})(1|(0))
0$1$#3
1
01
+`10
011
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY69CsJAEIT7eY2scsnBsZO/i6BY@hIisbCwsRC7mGc/9xLFLWZh9tthnrfX/XFNG3caU/BgL5XKVir40dGXZ0K8QgkiVC5Mw1yuCqmFcMf9gWGK5vLttDS7qEEBqUp@VW3h4tbHhQ45VibOC5Lnh/mRxrH7J6pQisYKWAu75jZWJ6VeW@MZhx3aptcO3RC1/QA) Link includes less slow test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
16$*0$&$*
```

Convert to unary, but also prefix 16 `0`s, so the binary value below has at least 16 digits.

```
+`(1+)\1
$+0
01
1
```

Convert to binary.

```
.*(.{8})(.{8})
$2$1
```

Swap the bottom eight bits with the next eight, and discard any remaining zeros.

```
(?<=1.{7})(1|(0))
$#2
```

XOR the top eight bits into the bottom eight bits, i.e. toggle any digit seven digits after a `1`.

```
1$
11001111001110100
```

Append `0x8180 ^ 0x1FF4` if the value ends in a `1`.

```
^((.{8}).{7}).
$+0${1}1110000001110100
```

Replace the value with two copies shifted eight bits and one bit right and also append `0xFF80 ^ 0x1FF4`.

```
+`1(.{15})(1|(0))
0$1$#3
```

(Destructively) XOR all of the values together.

```
1
01
+`10
011
1
```

Convert to decimal. Note that this takes `O(n²)` time, which makes the test cases take up to 25 seconds each on TIO, so I've also written a Retina 1 port but using fast binary to decimal conversion: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY07TgNBEETzuoYba3ZGanWN52cJyyGXQGYJCEgIgGy9PhYH4GLLrA2ig2qp9Pr1@8vn69szlzv3MC4awOJNtp4Io2MYHgmZOBuMINQ7ndo83BIShXDH@wN1qr3l2dnQ600EBaQZ@ZvWF07udniltYvjbKv9Cq3zB4aPkR1l/peaUDY7qDsenPr1i9KLi@IH2Yp/wmU8QcP3l4i6ZWHMpaJY6jbWtoch11R65tYiStqzIu2KZUSWmpB6VRGjxYLcqqUf) Link includes test cases.

Comment: You didn't have to use decimal I/O. I'd have suggested hexadecimal.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn Retina only has built-in base conversions between decimal and unary. You can slowly do base conversions for bases in between that use decimal digits as I have done here, but It will really struggle with bases higher than 10; the best I could do for hexadecimal to binary is a whopping 75 bytes, that compares to 30 for decimal to binary.

Comment: That's amazing, given that hex to binary is just "s/0/0000/; s/1/0001/; s/2/0010/" etc.

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn Each substitution is 2 bytes (newlines) plus 1 byte (digit) plus 4 bytes (bits); multiply that by 16 and you get a total of 112 bytes.

Comment: Heck, I'd even be willing to allow binary I/O.

Answer (score 3):

## [MIPS III](https://n64brew.dev/wiki/MIPS_III_instructions), <s>68</s> <s>60</s> <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
308800ff
00044a02
01285026
00085a00
016a5825
000b1042
00481026
316c0001
15800000
38429e74
03e00008
38427e00
```

Source:

```
rng:                                    # a0 = seed     
        andi    $t0, $a0, 0xFF          # s_lo
        srl     $t1, $a0, 8             # s_hi
        xor     $t2, $t1, $t0           # s_lo ^ s_hi
        sll     $t3, $t0, 8             # s_lo << 8
        or      $t3, $t3, $t2           # c = (s_lo << 8) | (s_lo ^ s_hi)
        
        srl     $v0, $t3, 1             # c / 2
        xor     $v0, $v0, $t0           # xor with s_lo
        
        andi    $t4, $t3, 1             # c odd
        bne     $t4,  $0, exit          
exit:   xori    $v0, $v0, 0x9E74        # xor twice if branch taken, eff. nop
                                        # 7E00 ^ E074
        jr      $ra
        xori    $v0, $v0, 0x7E00
```

Well I had to, didn't I? Even if MIPS is a terrible golfing language as far as assembly languages go, due to every single instruction being 4 bytes ([wasting instruction encoding bits](https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eisg/res/mips/opcodes)) and requiring unintuitive instruction re-ordering to not waste branch delay slots. It still beats out whatever actually was on the game ROM since I didn't have all of the mentioned Nintendo's [extraneous / unreachable code](https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64/blob/1372ae1bb7cbedc03df366393188f4f05dcfc422/src/engine/behavior_script.c#L39-L66).

-8 bytes from combining left and right shifts as in the math notation in the question. Also rewrote the comments to be much easier to follow.

-8 bytes from being smarter about `c` calculation thanks to m90.

-4 bytes from [rearranging instructions](https://n64brew.dev/wiki/MIPS_Assembly#Branch_Delay_Slot) to avoid a `nop` in the return jump branch delay slot. Here the control flow is weird: the branch (with offset 0) to a label at the delay slot causes the xor instruction to be executed twice if the branch is taken, once as part of the delay slot and again after branching, acting effectively as a no-op. AFAICT this is the intended behavior (at least supported by the MARS simulator).

Comment: Nintendo 64 uses MIPS, and a rabbit in the game is called MIPS

Comment: Yeah, I said so in my code discussion

Comment: The calculation of `$t2` is the same as the first calculation of `$t0`; reusing the value should save one instruction. I think another instruction can be saved by, instead of shifting and XORing `seed_lo` into the high part, waiting until after swapping the bytes, at which point it can be XORed into the low part without a shift.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 58 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a"q=%1>>8^(n=%1&255),q/2^n<<7^n^57460^q%%2*40564
```

Another port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 55 bytes

```
lambda n:(q:=n>>8^(n:=n&255))//2^n<<7^n^57460^q%2*40564
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BDoIwFETXeoofE02rIFhpi41wEWwTjKI1-tGKiZ7FDYnRO3kbIbia9xYz8_ycH9W-xPpVJKv3rSr8-CuP-Wm9yQEVuagE0zQ2BBsYMc4pDQJmcLmUBg2XkQjNZcjGUchF9K_fitKB9RAsQpbBjHEhPZCgPchARItZY7wzxkImPJiD1qrfOzuLFRmAn8JgeigtkuxaOWKpnnSgkqIxCu3BvZ13Oe62BKmmtDuv6y5_)

I'm late to the party, but yet another port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.

Answer (score 1):

## SM83/Z80, 24 bytes

Input in `bc`, output in `bc`.

```
79 A8 41 CB 19 1F 38 08
EE 74 F5 80 EE 9E 4F F1
A8 41 4F 78 EE 7E 47 C9
```

Explanation and disassembly:
First, here's the pseudocode I used for this.

```
s0 = r << 8;
s0 ^= r;
r = swab(s0);           // A
s1 = r & 1;
r >>= 1;                // B
if(!$1) r ^= 0x9E74;
r ^= s0 & 0xff          // C
r ^= 0x7E00             // D
```

Now the assembly:

```
sm64rng:
;; r starts in bc
    ld a,c          ;; 79
    xor b           ;; A8
    ld b,c          ;; 41
;; now s0 in ab, r in ca, after line A.
    rr c            ;; CB 19
    rra             ;; 1F
;; now s0 & 0xff in b, r in ca, s1 in cf, after line B.
    jr c, ifodd     ;; 38 08
    xor $74         ;; EE 74
    push af         ;; F5
    ld a,c          ;; 79
    xor $9E         ;; EE 9E
    ld c,a          ;; 4F
    pop af          ;; F1
ifodd:
;; now s0 & 0xff in b, r in ca, before line C.
    xor b           ;; A8
;; now after line C.
    ld b,c          ;; 41
    ld c,a          ;; 4F
    ld a,b          ;; 78
;; r now in ac
    xor $7E         ;; EE 7E
;; now after line D
    ld b,a          ;; 47
;; r now in bc
    ret             ;; C9
```

Note that this doesn't work on Z80studio, because the bit instructions are currently badly broken and `rr c` doesn't work properly, because it messes up the flags (and taken jumps go to the place two bytes before they should). But after some fixing of the Javascript, it can be tested!

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <del>141</del> <del>90</del> <del>79</del> <del>75</del> 74 bytes

Saved 67 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVDBcoIwFLz7Fa/OtIMO1CQlAYt66xf02NEO0oiZQmQg1HaQb6ePoON46K05JO/t2@xuUtaV6XYa8lhpZwLNCCCTBkqdwhK6U14b0M81FSdvhXujN0t9z7hYLMJID@WUbfRjdYyL9@2PkZUzifSMbXjgC@IhYco4I37bRagMMJvBy3ecF5mEuopTCUdl9pCqL6lB6aI2laX1EYaWYow3ijaBC4L4hLhAg3DuAhbWAw8ehgwPwjlZRwBWYXco4cFKoNC5QrHGDvtVlEqbTN8546YFbwVNO3YHT7d/vWPLyWSI3Y5urpzRa0rWpxT@nGJK/0kQ7gKjIvCxQ7QHOeV0Hf0djf1vNPzn10ImKs4giSsJ5gDJXiafsFXehyplYtRB4zCPi0Lp9FZjzBhhAhYX697TQhfPK5OHAfFvmRbqmW33Cw)

```rust
|mut n:u16|->u16{n^=n%256<<8;n=n%256*2^n.swap_bytes();n/2^57460-n%2*25204}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJNj5swEL3nV7zNYRUkorUpELYkuTXXSu2lUrUrETBglRgUO5ut0vz2dIzzQar2Vi62Z96892aY7U6b06lU2KpqstkZSNXtzEfseOxhurQnDiPQ1wgDC9Csz6bXoObnQB/RDAtMehY8gr2vVh7mcyQpnp6ga1kaNO0e659GwLSoZVVf6l4XTt1ROwriosyQCL8GIcY8LJcX9n3WIZmupUGdNW9CDwzdk3C8DqU0JwghiMlmLCxhZxcl@lKOhwUYDrBCheiEKqSq0CqbbosC7RbiTSgf3z5/wV6amnICbYkAeau0yZRxfoa9aSeXcJJDnz1CNFqcR/4XKF@twgv0NqbRcTSif7jJpJp4rpZsfnrPNl0jsNNZJZynSpJHV6OvP9A97Qy@8yCKZz5iFjLmg8@SZx90iWZhbI8oSQI6WBSxlxTORkmdPzqXUp1vRHbroNtKZRr1MBkfjnalDsex7zT9fuv6q@elg6auJV76h8vAuozDZ04uww8xi3wEPJ6F9KKoDUY84i/pv60F/9cazflrJ3KZNcgz3e90Xov8B9ZyWsityI1sFSU3WdfRxtxzjIOABTHmF2mr2YcumjdklMxYeI/sQxZ5PJ1@Aw)

```rust
fn rng(mut input: u16) -> u16 {
    let mut s0: u16;
    let s1: u16;

    s0 = (input & 0xFF) << 8; // shift low byte to high
    s0 ^= input;
    input = (s0 & 0xFF) << 8 | (s0 & 0xFF00) >> 8; // swap 8-bit halves
    s0 = (s0 & 0xFF) << 1 ^ input;
    s1 = s0 >> 1 ^ 0xFF80;
    if s0 & 1 != 0 {  // depending on s0 odd or even, XOR with one of 2 constants
        input = s1 ^ 0x8180; 
    } else {
        input = s1 ^ 0x1FF4; 
    }
    input
}

fn main(){
    // Example usage with given inputs
    let inputs1 = [12567, 60400, 1789, 0, 57460, 55882, 50550];  
    for &input in &inputs1 {
        println!("{} -> {}", input, rng(input));
    }
    println!();
    let inputs2 = [64917, 43605, 21674, 46497, 45151];
    for &input in &inputs2 {
        println!("{} -> {}", input, rng(input));
    }
    println!();
    // Special case to check bi-directional mapping
    println!("22026 <-> {}", rng(22026));
    println!("58704 <-> {}", rng(58704));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 51 bytes

It's a direct port of [Arnauld's Javascript answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250175/72767)

```perl
$_=($t=$_>>8^($_&=255))/2^$_<<7^$_^57460^$t%2*40564
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BDsIgEEX3XENswKQ6QxlAA/UEXgFWLkwa2ygbE88ugqmbn5@8efmzXB8TlcJTEDwHnsbRRcFTFxSRlAcVefLe1oxktYHI81btNJDRZbNKQvBXaE5TvHf1WK4dY4N/8G7dkHIg64ysgdGQhraYOzwPA5I6Oay8oCJjmQENwNC6IwP2e4AROac@85Jv8/1Z@gvtAaH0y/QF)